# Sending HTML as string in axios request is not working

Tags: javascript, html, http, axios, fetch

I'm trying to send a HTML string with axios, but is not working. This is the payload:

```
    const data = {
     send: new Date().toISOString(),
     userId: userInfo.id,
     title: broadcastName,
     subject:
      subjectInputText.trim().length > 0 ? subjectInputText : "No subject",
     Body: selectedTemplate.htmlToSend,
     contacts,
    };

   export const sentEmailBroadcast = (data) => async (dispatch) => 
        await customAxios.post("/Sendgrid/BroadcastSend", data);
```

where selectedTemplate.htmlToSend it's a full html document as string.
this is the output of console.log(selectedTemplate.htmlToSend)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG/><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <!--<![endif]-->
    
</head>

<body class="clean-body" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
    <!--[if IE]><div class="ie-browser"><![endif]-->
    <table class="nl-container" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; min-width: 320px; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                    <div style="background-color:#f3f3f3;overflow:hidden">
                        <div class="block-grid " style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 500px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; Margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: transparent;">
                            <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:transparent;">
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#f3f3f3;"><tr><td align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:500px"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:transparent"><![endif]-->
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="500" style="background-color:transparent;width:500px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"><![endif]-->
                                <div class="col num12" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 500px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 500px;">
                                    <div style="width:100% !important;">
                                        <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                                        <div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;">
                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                            <div class="img-container center  autowidth  fullwidth" align="center" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
                                                <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr style="line-height:0px"><td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center"><![endif]--><a href="https://beefree.io" target="_blank" style="outline:none" tabindex="-1"> <img class="center  autowidth  fullwidth" align="center" border="0" src alt="Image" title="Image" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 480px; display: block;" width="480"></a>
                                                <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                            </div>
                                            <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color:transparent;overflow:hidden">
                        <div class="block-grid " style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 500px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; Margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: transparent;">
                            <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:transparent;">
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:transparent;"><tr><td align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:500px"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:transparent"><![endif]-->
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="500" style="background-color:transparent;width:500px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;"><![endif]-->
                                <div class="col num12" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 500px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 500px;">
                                    <div style="width:100% !important;">
                                        <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                                        <div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                            <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
                                            <div style="color:#2d2d2d;font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; color: #2d2d2d; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.2; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 29px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 24px;"><strong><span style="font-size: 24px;">I'm a very important title</span></strong></span></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                            <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
                                            <div style="color:#777777;font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:5px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; color: #777777; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 19px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 16px;">I'm a subtitle: not as big as the title, but more descriptive</span></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                            <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
                                            <div style="color:#aaaaaa;font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:15px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; color: #aaaaaa; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 17px; margin: 0;">I'm a block of text and I like latin. Pellentesque vel dui sed orci faucibus iaculis. Suspendisse dictum magna id purus tincidunt rutrum. Hey look, I'm a fake link.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                            <div class="button-container" align="center" style="padding-top:15px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;"><tr><td style="padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px" align="center"><v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="" style="height:28.5pt; width:174pt; v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="14%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#7c4b96"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0"><center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px"><![endif]-->
                                                <div style="text-decoration:none;display:block;color:#ffffff;background-color:#7c4b96;border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;width:40%; width:calc(40% - 2px);;border-top:1px solid #7c4b96;border-right:1px solid #7c4b96;border-bottom:1px solid #7c4b96;border-left:1px solid #7c4b96;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;"><span style="padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;font-size:14px;display:inline-block;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.8; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 29px;"><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 25px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 25px;">READ MORE</span></span></span></div>
                                                <!--[if mso]></center></v:textbox></v:roundrect></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                            </div>
                                            <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color:#2d2d2d;overflow:hidden">
                        <div class="block-grid " style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 500px; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; Margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color: transparent;">
                            <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;background-color:transparent;">
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color:#2d2d2d;"><tr><td align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:500px"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:transparent"><![endif]-->
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="500" style="background-color:transparent;width:500px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px;"><![endif]-->
                                <div class="col num12" style="min-width: 320px; max-width: 500px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; width: 500px;">
                                    <div style="width:100% !important;">
                                        <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                                        <div style="border-top:0px solid transparent; border-left:0px solid transparent; border-bottom:0px solid transparent; border-right:0px solid transparent; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
                                            <!--<![endif]-->
                                            <table class="social_icons" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
                                                        <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" valign="top">
                                                            <table class="social_table" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-tspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; mso-table-bspace: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0;" valign="top">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr style="vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; text-align: center;" align="center" valign="top">
                                                                        <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0;" valign="top"><a href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="repository_path/img/t-circle-white/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; display: block;"></a></td>
                                                                        <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0;" valign="top"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="repository_path/img/t-circle-white/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; display: block;"></a></td>
                                                                        <td style="word-break: break-word; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0;" valign="top"><a href="https://instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img width="32" height="32" src="repository_path/img/t-circle-white/instagram@2x.png" alt="Instagram" title="Instagram" style="text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; border: 0; display: block;"></a></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <!--[if mso]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif"><![endif]-->
                                            <div style="color:#bbbbbb;font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1.2;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; color: #bbbbbb; font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-line-height-alt: 14px;">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.2; text-align: center; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 17px; margin: 0;"><span style="font-size: 14px;">This is a sample template from BEE free email editor</span><br><span style="font-size: 14px;">Visit <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;" href="https://beefree.io" target="_blank" rel="noopener">beefree.io</a></span>&nbsp;to create beautiful and rich email messages at no cost.</span></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                            <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!-->
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                                <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--[if (IE)]></div><![endif]-->
</body>

</html>
```

and the typepof selectedTeamplate.htmlToSend its string, but when I send the POST Request, what I see in the payload is something like this (is just a fragment):
for some reason it's adding "↵"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">↵<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">↵↵<head>↵   <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG/><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]-->↵  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">↵    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">↵    <!--[if !mso]><!-->↵    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">↵  <!--<![endif]-->↵   <title></title>↵    <!--[if !mso]><!-->↵    <!--<![endif]-->↵   <style type="text/css">↵        body {↵         margin: 0;↵         padding: 0;↵        }↵↵     table,↵     td,↵        tr {↵           vertical-align: top;↵           border-collapse: collapse;↵     }↵↵     * {↵            line-height: inherit;↵      }↵↵     a[x-apple-data-detectors=true] {↵           color: inherit !important;↵         text-decoration: none !important;↵      }↵  </style>↵   <style type="text/css" id="media-query">↵       @media (max-width: 520px) {↵↵           .block-grid,↵           .col {↵             min-width: 320px !important;↵               max-width: 100% !important;↵                display: block !important;↵         }↵↵         .block-grid {↵              width: 100% !important;↵            }↵↵         .col {↵             width: 100% !important;↵            }↵↵         .col>div {↵             margin: 0 auto;↵            }↵↵         img.fullwidth,↵         img.fullwidthOnMobile {↵                max-width: 100% !important;↵            }↵↵         .no-stack .col {↵               min-width: 0 !important;↵               display: table-cell !important;↵            }↵↵         .no-stack.two-up .col {↵                width: 50% !important;↵         }↵↵         .no-stack .col.num2 {↵              width: 16.6% !important;↵           }↵↵         .no-stack .col.num3 {↵              width: 25% !important;↵         }↵↵         .no-stack .col.num4 {↵              width: 33% !important;↵         }↵↵         .no-stack .col.num5 {↵              width: 41.6% !important;↵           }↵↵         .no-stack .col.num6 {↵              width: 50% !important;↵         }↵↵         .no-stack .col.num7 {↵
```

So the format its weird, because when sending the request it changes the htmlToSend and add the "↵" and is not working. I'm using axios.

Answer (score 0):

↵ means a newline. Nothing to worry about. Unless something goes wrong server-side, it's working fine.

Comment: thanks :) when I send that payload, and the backend send the email, I receive the email with those ↵, so is it a backend issue?

Comment: Try removing the newlines before you send it. That makes the request smaller anyway